# Use the count of a has_many relation to select - using having?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Order has_many deliveries

Order has a column number_of_deliveries_paid_for

How do I select all the orders where the number of deliveries (COUNT(deliveries.id)) is less than number_of_deliveries_paid_for

At the moment, I'm doing:

```
Order.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN deliveries ON deliveries.order_id = orders.id')
     .select('orders.*, COUNT(deliveries.id) AS delivery_count')
     .select { |o| o if o.number_of_deliveries_paid_for > o.delivery_count }
```

But this returns an array, it'd be nice to return an ActiveRecord::Relation, and I imagine it would be more efficient to do it in sql.

Update ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

This seems to work

```
Order.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN deliveries ON deliveries.order_id = orders.id')
     .group('orders.id')
     .having('COUNT(deliveries.id) < orders.number_of_deliveries_paid_for')
```

I can chain other scopes on the end of it etc.  But if I add `.count` to the end, I get the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column
'orders.number_of_deliveries_paid_for' in 'having clause':
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, orders.id AS orders_id FROM `orders`
LEFT OUTER JOIN deliveries ON deliveries.order_id = orders.id GROUP BY orders.id 
HAVING COUNT(deliveries.id) < orders.number_of_deliveries_paid_for
```

which makes me anxious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to write that in Ruby, but from an SQL point of view, I feel like you need a sub-query to aggregate the number of deliveries by order.

Something like that (I type directly to SO -- please forgive typos or stupid syntax errors):

```
SELECT orders.* FROM orders 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C, deliveries.order_id AS ID
                                        FROM deliveries 
                                        GROUP BY deliveries.order_id) AS S
                ON orders.id = S.ID
                WHERE S.C < orders.number_of_deliveries_paid_for
                   OR (deliveries.id IS NULL AND orders.number_of_deliveries_paid_for > 0);
```

---

**EDIT:** As a matter of fact, this is much more simple using `ORDER BY ... HAVING`:

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS C FROM orders 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN deliveries 
                        ON deliveries.order_id = orders.id
       GROUP BY orders.id 
       HAVING C < orders.number_of_deliveries_paid_for
           OR (deliveries.id IS NULL AND orders.number_of_deliveries_paid_for > 0);
```

And for the curious, here is my test case:

```
mysql> select * from orders;
+------+---------+-------------------------------+
| id   | name    | number_of_deliveries_paid_for |
+------+---------+-------------------------------+
|    1 | Order 1 |                             0 |
|    2 | Order 2 |                             2 |
|    3 | Order 3 |                             3 |
+------+---------+-------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from deliveries;
+----+----------+
| id | order_id |
+----+----------+
|  1 |        2 |
|  2 |        2 |
|  3 |        3 |
|  4 |        3 |
+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from orders JOIN deliveries ON deliveries.order_id = orders.id    -> ;
+------+---------+-------------------------------+----+----------+
| id   | name    | number_of_deliveries_paid_for | id | order_id |
+------+---------+-------------------------------+----+----------+
|    2 | Order 2 |                             2 |  1 |        2 |
|    2 | Order 2 |                             2 |  2 |        2 |
|    3 | Order 3 |                             3 |  3 |        3 |
|    3 | Order 3 |                             3 |  4 |        3 |
+------+---------+-------------------------------+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As a side note, see the difference between `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
mysql> select *, COUNT(*) from orders LEFT JOIN deliveries ON deliveries.order_id = orders.id group by orders.id;
+------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------+
| id   | name    | number_of_deliveries_paid_for | id   | order_id | COUNT(*) |
+------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------+
|    1 | Order 1 |                             0 | NULL |     NULL |        1 |
|    2 | Order 2 |                             2 |    1 |        2 |        2 |
|    3 | Order 3 |                             3 |    3 |        3 |        2 |
+------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *, COUNT(*) from orders JOIN deliveries ON deliveries.order_id = orders.id group by orders.id;
+------+---------+-------------------------------+----+----------+----------+
| id   | name    | number_of_deliveries_paid_for | id | order_id | COUNT(*) |
+------+---------+-------------------------------+----+----------+----------+
|    2 | Order 2 |                             2 |  1 |        2 |        2 |
|    3 | Order 3 |                             3 |  3 |        3 |        2 |
+------+---------+-------------------------------+----+----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Are you saying that group by ... having is a good way of doing this?

Comment: But I need to have all the orders where there are no deliveries, so I need to do a left join!

Comment: OK, many edits after ... Apparently, the two options (sub-query and `having` clause) works. In both cases, I extended the test to take into account the case where there is no delivery for an order. For that reason I re-introduced the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: And finally, the option using `GROUP BY ... HAVING` should be more efficient since there is less temptation here for MySQL to create a temporary.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up adding a deliveries_count column to order, which was much easier!